# ERROR: init: ttyS0 (/dev/ttyS0) main process (1612) terminated with status 1

Tags: linux, tty, io, init, amazon-ec2

I'm getting the following errors every 10-30 seconds on a virtual `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5 2 Server` on `Amazons EC2`.

```
Sep 23 09:57:05 ServerName init: ttyS0 (/dev/ttyS0) main process (1612) terminated with status 1
Sep 23 09:57:05 ServerName init: ttyS0 (/dev/ttyS0) main process ended, respawning
Sep 23 09:57:05 ServerName agetty[1613]: /dev/ttyS0: tcgetattr: Input/output error
```

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I could go about fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: What process is 1612?

Comment: I'm not totally sure as the process number keeps incrementing by 1 every error (from 1 upwards).

Comment: Try the steps in [this post](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1368099).  Deleting the file will cause it to be recreated.  If that doesn't help submit a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have tried that post and it didn't resolve the issue. So it's looking like it might have to be a ticket.

Comment: Yup, and like the post says it may be affecting others in the server environment... Makes me curious :)

Comment: I have an old Amazon Linux https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/ server that was driving me nuts with this. I finally thought to log `for n in {0..10}; do ps auxww; sleep 1; done` to a file, then search for the `terminated with status 1` pid number. Discovered it was `agetty` and that lead me here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A virtual Red Hat installation probably doesn't have any serial ports connected (which is what /dev/ttyS0 is: COM1 in DOS parlance), so trying to start agetty to listen to the serial port is doomed to fail. Find the line in /etc/inittab that contains agetty and ttyS0 and change

`respawn` to `off`.

EDIT: In case the system is using upstart, as in redhat 6, do

```
stop ttyS0
```

to stop the service now, and do

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/ttyS0.override
```

to prevent starting the service after a reboot according to https://askubuntu.com/a/468250/146273

For documentation purposes, you might also consider doing:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/init/ttyS0.conf <<EOF

# Disabled. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157489/9745
EOF
```

Further reading: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#disabling-a-job-from-automatically-starting

Comment: Hi, I have just had a looked in that file and there isn't any line about agetty. All seem to be commented out and talking about the fact that "inittab is only used by upstart for the default runlevel" and then list a load of start up options.

Comment: Try "find /etc -type f -exec grep ttyS0 {} +" to see in what file ttyS0 is mentioned. I'm more a Debian man than Red Hat... (the find instead of grep -r is because grep follows symlinks and find doesn't)

Comment: Looks like its in two file "/etc/init/ttyS0.conf" and "/etc/init/serial.conf". ttyS0.conf has 5 lines `start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] ||
stop on starting runlevel [016] ||
respawn || 
instance /dev/ttyS0 || 
exec /sbin/agetty /dev/ttyS0 115200 vt100-nav ||`. I have split each line up with `||`, would I change 'respawn' in this file?

Comment: Try first `stop ttyS0` and then renaming the ttyS0.conf file to e.g. ttyS0.conf.NOT. This is part of "upstart", which I don't have experience with.

Comment: Alright I will give that a go, will a reboot be required?

Comment: No, the stop stops it trying to start it over and over, and renaming it prevents it from trying again after a reboot.

Comment: I have followed all of those step and rebooted and the error is not longer showing, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors after changing from Xen to KVM on my VPS, but about **tty1**, not **tty1S**. The fix was to replace `/etc/init/tty1.conf` with `/etc/init/tty1.conf.dpkg-dist`. The old file referred to the `/dev/hvc0`, a Xen virtual device which no longer existed.